# How to pivot pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

My DataFrame looks like this:

[image]

How can I have `Budget` for each `Division`?

**Should look like this:**

[image]

```
import pandas as pd 

df=pd.DataFrame ({
'TotalAmount':[500,600,780,900],
'Division': ['Commercial Auto', 'Commercial Auto','Surety', 'Worker''s Comp'],
'MonthNumber':[1,2,3,4],
'YearNumber': [2019,2019,2019,2019],
'Budget': [550,570,700,920],
'PostDate': ['2019-01-01', '2019-02-01','2019-03-01','2019-04-01']
})
#print(df)
t = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Budget', index='Division',columns='MonthNumber',fill_value=0).reset_index()
print(t)
```

Comment: Is it important to have the output in this form? If you use values=['Budget', 'TotalAmount'] in your pivot_table command you will get a wider version that might be sufficient.

Comment: Yes. That is important to have output in form like that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['TotalAmount','Budget'] , index='Division',columns='MonthNumber',fill_value=0).T.unstack(0).T.reset_index()
df1.columns.name = None
df1 = df1.sort_values(['Division','level_1'], 0, [True,False])
df1.Division = df1.level_1.where(df1.level_1 == 'Budget', df1.Division)
df1 = df1.drop('level_1', 1)
```

Result:

```
          Division    1    2    3    4
1  Commercial Auto  500  600    0    0
0           Budget  550  570    0    0
3           Surety    0    0  780    0
2           Budget    0    0  700    0
5     Workers Comp    0    0    0  900
4           Budget    0    0    0  920
```

Comment: That's awesome!  What is T in the first line? Is is just the giving name ?

Comment: `T` stands for [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html), i.e. swap rows with cols.